# RNLocalize gets an undefined object on RNLocalize.initialContants

Tags: react-native

I got an error as image below! I don't know why it's happen? Can anyone give me known and fix it's to help me?

[image: error]

I used:

```
    "react": "16.8.3"
    "react-native": "0.59.9"
    "react-native-localize": "1.3.1"
    "react-native-cli": "2.0.1"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be you didn't properly linking the `RNLocalize` with your project.

In terminal run - `react-native link react-native-localize` and double check on your iOS and android project following files has the linking code or not. If not then do manually linking process.

Following are the steps to Manually link that project

**For iOS**

Add this line to your ios/Podfile file, then run pod install.

```
target 'YourAwesomeProject' do
  # …
  pod 'RNLocalize', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-localize'
end
```

**For android**

Add the following lines to android/settings.gradle:

```
include ':react-native-localize'
project(':react-native-localize').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-localize/android')
```

Add the implementation line to the dependencies in android/app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation project(':react-native-localize')
}
```

Add the import and link the package in MainApplication.java:

```
import com.reactcommunity.rnlocalize.RNLocalizePackage; // <- add the RNLocalizePackage import

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  // …

  @Override
  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
    List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
    // …
    packages.add(new RNLocalizePackage());
    return packages;
  }

  // …
}
```